# how does django oscar register the user model in the admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

my custom User

```
rom django.db import models

from oscar.apps.customer.abstract_models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)  # new

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

my extra settings

```
'users.apps.UsersConfig'  
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

The model works correctly in the dashboard, but I didn't find the code that register user and user groups in admin panel. How oscar do that?